# What is the safest (or most elegant or shortest) way to change to the directory from where a script is called?

Tags: bash, cd-command, posix, pwd

I wondered what might be a safe or the Unix compatible way to change to the directory from which a script is called.

These two methods even work in a directory with spaces and special characters in it, without using quotes. But there might be some situations where this might not work. Or is there?

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $(dirname $0)
pwd
cd ${0%/*}
pwd

~/test 1"\ ü`\($$ ./cd.sh
/home/syss/test 1"\ ü`\($
/home/syss/test 1"\ ü`\($
```

Comment: you tagged bash and gave a bash script; are you looking for a bash-centric solution, or across any shell?

Comment: basically I am interested in bash, zsh and busybox

Comment: Your test is not valid. In your case `dirname $0` is `.` since you called the script as `./ch.sh`. If you had called it with its full pathname then you would see that quotes are required because then `dirname` would produce a path that has a space in it.

Comment: Might be tricky if the script is piped to the shell via standard input.

Comment: Parameter expansions without double quoting is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beware that `$0` can be a relative path, so calling `cd` twice might not work. Apart from that, extracting the directory part of `$0` works in *most* cases. *Most* is not the same as *all*. Some cases where it can fail include:

- The script is not invoked by running its path but by calling a shell on it, e.g. `bash myscript` (which does a `PATH` lookup).
- The script is moved during its execution.

As long as you document that your script must be called without shenanigans, taking the directory part of `$0` is ok.

You need to be a little careful; it's possible for `$0` to not contain a slash at all, if it was found via an empty `PATH` entry or, with some shells, a `PATH` entry for `.`. This case is worth supporting, and it means you need to take precautions with `${0%/*}`.

The `dirname` approach isn't completely straightforward either. The command substitution eats up newlines at the end. And with both approaches you need to take care that the string could begin with `-` and be interpreted as an option; pass `--` to terminate a command's option list.

```
case "$0" in
  */*) cd -- "${0%/*}";;
  *) cd -- "$0";;
esac
```

or

```
cd -- "$(dirname -- "$0"; echo /)"
```

Regarding the double quotes, you're asking the wrong question. `"$0"` is the value of the parameter `0`. [`$0`, unquoted, is the value of the parameter `0` split at characters in `IFS` with each element then interpreted as a glob pattern and replaced by matching files if there are any (that latter part only if globbing is not turned off)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters). You don't mean the value of the parameter `0` split at characters in `IFS` with each element then interpreted as a glob pattern and replaced by matching files if there are any (that latter part only if globbing is not turned off), do you? You mean the value of the parameter `0`. So write what you mean: `"$0"`.

The only reason your tests didn't choke is that you didn't try it with problematic names and you tested with a specific shell that happens to repair your mistake in this specific scenario. With a directory name like `foo bar`, you end up passing two arguments `foo` and `bar` to the `cd` command; bash's `cd` command interprets this as “change to the directory obtained by concatenating `foo`, a space and `bar`” so it happens to build back the right name. A different shell might interpret this as “complain about a spurious argument”, “change to the directory `foo`”, or “change to the directory obtained by replacing `foo` by `bar` in the current working directory”. With bash, your script would fail if the name contained two consecutive spaces, for example.